# how to act on only one class to make it visible or invisible

Tags: javascript

I have a purchase order with 500 items, in this example I only put 3 items

When I click on "ajouter au panier" of item 2001 I would like the "retirer du panier" div to be visible just for this item

When the "retirer du panier" div is visible I would like to make it invisible by clicking on "retirer du panier"

For NOW, my code works but on all divs at the same time

```js
function myFunction() {
  const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");
  for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    nodeList[i].style.visibility = " visible";
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");
  for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    nodeList[i].style.visibility = " hidden";
  }

}
```

```html
<a data-nom="2001" class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier b-items__item__add-to-cart" onclick="myFunction();">
                       ajouter au panier
                     </a><br>

<div class="panel" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <a data-qte2="0" class=" ajouter-panier ">
                         retirer panier
                       </a><br>
</div>
<a data-nom="2002" class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier b-items__item__add-to-cart" onclick="myFunction();">
                       ajouter au panier
                    </a><br>

<div class="panel" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <a data-qte2="0" class=" ajouter-panier ">
                         retirer panier
                       </a><br>
</div>
<a data-nom="2003" class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier b-items__item__add-to-cart" onclick="myFunction();">
                       ajouter au panier
                     </a><br>

<div class="panel" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <a data-qte2="0" class=" ajouter-panier ">
                         retirer panier
                       </a>
```

Comment: Looks like you already know how to act on only one class: by using `document.querySelector()`. If you want to narrow down what you select, add more classes!

Answer (score 0):

Use this and nextElementSibling:

```
<a data-nom=... onclick="myFunction(this);return false;">
```

so

```
<a data-nom="2002"
  class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier b-items__item__add-to-cart"
  onclick="myFunction(this);return false;">
    ajouter au panier
</a><br>

<div class="panel" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <a data-qte2="0" class="ajouter-panier">retirer panier</a><br>
</div>
```

And in function myFunction():

```
function myFunction(e) {
  e.nextElementSibling.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: Give an example of “…” so the OP can understand

Comment: Thanks for the code but it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for the answer
In my question we have to realize the code